# Is it possible to insert the Email Subject of an envelope into the document that you are sending with DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

I want to insert the Email Subject of an envelope into the document that you are sending with DocuSign, just like Envelope ID appeared on the document automatically. Is that possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrU90.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Omxx.png)

The email subject is dynamic. We send envelopes to different people with particular subjects. For instance, a email subject like this one: [Store ID] [Store Name]- Signing Instructions of Store Cooperation Agreement.

I know the regular configuration doesn't work. It might be possible to do it through an API or an Integration……

Hope you can help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to dynamically alter the document contents itself once you upload the file. However, you can change the email subject of the email notification depending on the recipient by using the emailNotification.emailSubject property under the recipient object. Please refer to the below page for more information about this property:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_recipients_signers_emailnotification_emailsubject